# Add custom http response headers for all cpanel whm pages

Tags: http, header, cpanel, whm

I want to add custom http response headers for all cpanel whm pages.

I modified /usr/local/cpanel/Cpanel/Server/Response.pm and add a custom header

but i have no idea to load those changes. Maybe we need to recompile cpsrvd ?

Can someone explain do that load my changes ?